# BaGet private repository: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, nuget, tls1.2

As mentioned in the title, I'm facing an issue with a private BaGet Repository.

We have few dev machine that needs to run with the latest available version of Windows7.
On those machine we aren't able to connect to a specific BaGet repository.

```
[xxx-BaGet] Unable to load the service index for source https://xxx/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I tried to get over this issues following those guides

[How to enable TLS 1.2 on clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client) and [Deprecating TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on NuGet.org](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/)

After that running this app [api.nuget.org connection tester](https://gist.github.com/zivkan/5291f507c8c5724d41a18357b7afcd30) is seems all is set up, but still the error shows.

I've imported the crt from our repo.

Now I'm stuck and I don't know what to do next.

Someone have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!